# sending message in all guilds on certain event in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I used this code to send a message to a certain channel named "giveaway-index" but the problem is that it only send message to the channel named "giveaway-index" only in one guild. I want it to send the message to all guilds that have a channel named "giveaway-index". is there any way I can do it?

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if "GIVEAWAY" in message.content:
      if message.author.id == 294882584201003009:
        global channel_id
        channel = discord.utils.get(message.guild.channels, name='giveaway-index')
        channel_id = channel.id
        print(channel_id) 
        channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)
        await channel.send("blah blah blah")
```

Comment: `for guild in client.guilds` gives out all guilds. Then you just need to check if the channel is in this guild and send the message to it.

Answer (score 0):

`for guild in client.guilds` loops through all the guilds. Then you just have to check if the channel with **"giveaway-index"** is in the guild and send the message.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if "GIVEAWAY" in message.content:
        if message.author.id == 294882584201003009:
            for guild in client.guilds: # looping through all guilds your bot is in
                channel = discord.utils.get(guild.text_channels, name='giveaway-index') # getting channel
                if channel: # checking if channel is in the guild
                    await channel.send("blah blah blah")
```

Comment: it just print the message in only one guild multiple times
it doesn't print in all guilds

Comment: Did it work for you?